# loading XML Data in to an Existing Database with Persisting ID's C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

Hi I'm trying to read from a XML file and pump the data in to a existing Database. I'm in a situation where I need the ID's to stay the same from the XML File and I am using EF6.

Everything is actually working when I run this without the Identity disabled part. however that would mean all the ID's are automatically incremented and not the ones I set in to the DB.

My question is simple How  do I using this approach Force the ID I provide to be used in the Database ?

I'm translating between a EDMX objects and my DTO objects so I could read from the XML file without having noise from the EDMX file messing with my XML reading. 
Also I know this is not pretty but it is almost a one time scenario and I wanted to eliminate the possibilities of human Error as much as possible as it is expected that I have to scale this approach up to about 50+ other tables with various foreign keys and primary keys. simply too much data for a manual hand written Data transfer.

```
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Model.Logic.DTO.DTORespondents, Model.Datamodel.Respondents>();
            });

            using (var ctxTest = new Model.Datamodel.MedicalNavigationTestDBEntities())
            {
                using (var transaction = ctxTest.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    //EXEC sys.sp_identitycolumnforreplication table_object_id, 1


                    string[] arrFilenames = Directory.GetFiles(fileNamePath);
                    List<Model.Datamodel.Respondents> dbRespondentsImportList = new List<Model.Datamodel.Respondents>();
                    foreach (string filename in arrFilenames)
                    {
                        var objRespondent = Program.DeSerializeObject<Model.Logic.DTO.DTORespondents>(Path.Combine(fileNamePath, filename));

                        dbRespondentsImportList.Add(Mapper.Map<Model.Datamodel.Respondents>(objRespondent));
                    }
                    foreach (Model.Datamodel.Respondents objRespondents in dbRespondentsImportList)
                    {
                        ctxTest.Respondents.Add(objRespondents);
                        //ctxTest.Respondents.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CollectUrl.Equals(objRespondents.CollectUrl)).Id = objRespondents.Id;

                    }
                    ctxTest.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"declare @object_ids int;
                                                        set @object_ids = (select[object_id] from sys.objects WHERE [name] = 'respondents')
                                                        select @object_ids
                                                        EXEC sys.sp_identitycolumnforreplication @object_ids, 1");
                    ctxTest.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Respondents] ON");
                    ctxTest.SaveChanges();
                    ctxTest.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Respondents] OFF");
                    ctxTest.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"declare @object_ids int;
                                                        set @object_ids = (select[object_id] from sys.objects WHERE [name] = 'respondents')
                                                        select @object_ids
                                                        EXEC sys.sp_identitycolumnforreplication @object_ids, 1");
                    transaction.Commit()    ;
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is the necessity to keep the ID \ insert the ID? This has potential dangers if you have an ID that is typically automatically set and isnt recommended

Comment: @SimonPrice I am well aware of this. but I will break up relationships if the ID changes. But thanks for reminding me of why this is a bad way to do this. I however do not see any alternative for my requirements.

Comment: I think this is impossible task with EF6 since even if you enable identity insert, EF won't send your identity PK values as part of the `INSERT` commands. This behavior has been fixed in EF Core, I don't believe EF6 would ever get that.

Comment: Might be a better approach to create a stored procedure, pass the XML *as is*, and use `MERGE` within this SP to perform a *single-pass-upsert*.

Comment: @shnugo that might be beyond my abilities. I don't see how I would make such a stored procedure.

Comment: @IvanStoev hmm so if I can change to EF Core I could potentially get it to work the way I intended ?

Comment: @Helbo, If you'd provide a sample of your XML and the corresponding DDL we might help you with a stored procedure...

Comment: @Shnugo problem is I got more than 50 different XML structures. That have to go to more than 50 different Tables. with their individual references and ID's that have to be correct.
So giving you one sample of each wouldn't be a viable solution either. And I'm not sure I could learn stored procedures of this kind of difficulties in time. 
Is a much safer bet for me to stick with what I know and hack something viable together.

Comment: It will, but EF Core has its own pitfalls and generally is not stable, so in case you don't use simple CRUID (no complex queries) I wouldn't recommend switching. May be you should look at some 3rd party EF extensions like https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions

Comment: @Helbo using a merge statement is rather simple and a very clean way of doing it. Dont be affraid of trying it and failing, eventually youll get it, and then they will all fall into place.  The alternative is thinking its too difficult and not doing it and then not getting anywhere

Comment: I've found my solution and implemented it. it is less than ideal and took me several days to complete. However I did it. I handcrafted each individual tables data in a Insert into statement. I did not like doing it and will be very interested if anyone will come up with a better answer for this in this thread. if nothing else to make sure someone else never ends up in the same situation again. Worst part is I'm only half way done now I have to do the same process for another Database just it is slightly different.